# Group SAS rows based on conditions

Tags: sql, sas

I am new to SAS community and need your help for one of my analysis. I have a table like below:

| ID VAR | Group | Breach | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 202001 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 202002 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 202003 |
| 4 | A | 1 | 202004 |
| 5 | A | 1 | 202005 |
| 6 | A | 1 | 202006 |
| 7 | A | 0 | 202007 |
| 8 | A | 1 | 202008 |
| 9 | A | 1 | 202009 |
| 10 | A | 0 | 202010 |
| 11 | A | 1 | 202011 |
| 12 | A | 0 | 202012 |
| 13 | A | 1 | 202101 |
| 14 | A | 1 | 202102 |
| 15 | A | 0 | 202103 |
| 16 | A | 1 | 202104 |
| 17 | A | 1 | 202105 |
| 18 | A | 1 | 202106 |
| 19 | A | 1 | 202107 |
| 20 | A | 0 | 202108 |
| 21 | A | 1 | 202109 |

I want only to select rows which has 2 consecutive breaches within a group A , only once in a block of consecutive 0's or 1's. So basically I want the following table as output:

| ID VAR | Group | Breach | Month | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 202001 | No |
| 2 | A | 1 | 202002 | Yes |
| 3 | A | 1 | 202003 | No |
| 4 | A | 1 | 202004 | No |
| 5 | A | 1 | 202005 | No |
| 6 | A | 1 | 202006 | No |
| 7 | A | 0 | 202007 | No |
| 8 | A | 1 | 202008 | No |
| 9 | A | 1 | 202009 | Yes |
| 10 | A | 0 | 202010 | No |
| 11 | A | 1 | 202011 | No |
| 12 | A | 0 | 202012 | No |
| 13 | A | 1 | 202101 | No |
| 14 | A | 1 | 202102 | Yes |
| 15 | A | 0 | 202103 | No |
| 16 | A | 1 | 202104 | No |
| 17 | A | 1 | 202105 | Yes |
| 18 | A | 1 | 202106 | No |
| 19 | A | 1 | 202107 | No |
| 20 | A | 0 | 202108 | No |
| 21 | A | 1 | 202109 | No |

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome :-)

Try this

```
data have;
input IDVAR Group $ Breach Month;
datalines;
1 A 1 202001
2 A 1 202002
3 A 1 202003
4 A 1 202004
5 A 1 202005
6 A 1 202006
7 A 0 202007
8 A 1 202008
9 A 1 202009
10 A 0 202010
11 A 1 202011
12 A 0 202012
13 A 1 202101
14 A 1 202102
15 A 0 202103
16 A 1 202104
17 A 1 202105
18 A 1 202106
19 A 1 202107
20 A 0 202108
21 A 1 202109
;

data want;
   set have;
   by Group;
   if Breach = 1 then c + 1;
   if first.Group then c = 1;
   if Breach = 0 then c = 0;
   Result = ifc(c = 2, 'Yes', 'No');
run;
```

Comment: Anytime :-) Please remember to mark the answer as an accepted solution. This help other users navigate

Answer (score 1):

A DOW loop that uses the `BY` group processing option 'NOTSORTED' can be used to compute your result.  Variables that hold an assertion result (i.e. flag values) are often left simply as `0` meaning assertion was false, and `1` true.

Example (Draycut's data, extended to have consecutive breach=0 states at idvar=23):

```
data have;
input IDVAR Group $ Breach Month;
datalines;
1 A 1 202001
2 A 1 202002
3 A 1 202003
4 A 1 202004
5 A 1 202005
6 A 1 202006
7 A 0 202007
8 A 1 202008
9 A 1 202009
10 A 0 202010
11 A 1 202011
12 A 0 202012
13 A 1 202101
14 A 1 202102
15 A 0 202103
16 A 1 202104
17 A 1 202105
18 A 1 202106
19 A 1 202107
20 A 0 202108
21 A 1 202109
22 A 0 202110
23 A 0 202111
24 A 0 202112
;

data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.breach);
    set have;
    by group breach notsorted;
    result = (_n_ = 2);
    output;
  end;
  label result = 'Flag for 1st consecutive repeated state of Breach';
run;
```